# Embed Q3DSurface into QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt 5.7 and I'm aware that there is a Surface3D QML type and it works well except performance in my case. I hope that pure C++ would be faster.

So to speed up my QML-based GUI application which deals with 3D data visualization, I'd like to have a proxy for Q3DSurface to embed it inside Qml application. For this I need to subclass from QQuickItem and then I need to set this custom class as a container for Q3DSurface instance. Is that right?
What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look into this example:http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-qmlsurface-example.html

As far as I understand the code it shows how to embed Surface3D into your QML-app.

To be able to render onto it afterwards you can connect to the update-method. I am not sure how to make sure that this could be done after Surface3D-rendering is ready.

Comment: Ok, this is pure OpenGL solution. But what if Q3DSurface class matches my requirements for data rendering...is there any way to use it inside QML?

Comment: Yes, I saw this example - it's based on QML types, it's fine when you don't have to render much 3D data. I checked my application based on Q3DSurface and works fine, but I have plenty of items in QML. Q3DSurface is a c++ way to render 3D graphs. So now I'm looking for the way to combine my QML part with Q3DSurface(c++).

Comment: You want to mixup C++ and QML in one rendersurface?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But how QQuickItem would know that it's a container for 3D surface renderer?

Comment: You can create a subclass with a property, which tells this to your Item for instance.